# LWC div don't working as expected once the value is atribuited via URL

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, callout

I've created a LWC which takes some fields information from the URL and add to the expected variables, every other field worked fine except checkboxes, that is attributing the value but once I'm creating the case, It's getting an error without context, but once I deselect the checkbox (and reselect or just leave It) the value is being truelly affected to the field and not getting error:

this is the HTML:

```
<div style="padding-bottom:8px">
    <lightning-input type="checkbox"  name="If possible can Launch Sooner" label="If possible can Launch Sooner" value={selectedCanLaunchSooner} onchange={handleCanLaunchSoonerChange} checked={selectedCanLaunchSooner}> </lightning-input>    
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
if(this.currentPageReference.state.can_launch_sooner__c != null){
  this.selectedCanLaunchSooner = this.currentPageReference.state.can_launch_sooner__c;
}
```

The error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I image that the variable from "currentPageReference" needs to the properly attributed to a boolean format, but how to do that?

Comment: I've used the attribute "!!" at the beginning of the "currentPageReference" variable and It worked! now is something like: "!!this.currentPageReference.state.can_launch_sooner__c;"

Comment: You can add your own answer (see [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer)). We would encourage you to do so, if this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to use a string value of `'true'` in the input element.

By your snippet, you could remove the if statement and simplify it as a one-liner:

```js
// note the '?' operator in case the `this.currentPageReference` attribute is undefined.
// in a scenario like this, it would return early as a falsy value and the !! operator
// would then convert it to a boolean as your attribute requires.
this.selectedCanLaunchSooner = !!this.currentPageReference?.state.can_launch_sooner__c;
```